# Python: Function to flatten generator containing another generator

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator

I would like to know how to write python function which can flatten generator which yields another generators or iteables (which can also yield another generators/iterables ... possibly infinitely).

Here is example:

`gen(gen(1,2,3), gen(4,5,6), [7,8,9], [gen(10,11,12), gen(13,14,15)])`

note: `gen` - means generator object, content between parentheses after `gen` is data that will generator `gen` yield.

The expected result after "flattening":
`gen(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15)`

It is necessary for the flatten function to return generator too! (because otherwise, the preceeding usage of generators would be meaningless).

Just to note, I am using python 3.

Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The easiest way is a recursive flattening function.  Assuming you want to descend into every iterable except for strings, you could do this:

```
def flatten(it):
    for x in it:
        if (isinstance(x, collections.Iterable) and
            not isinstance(x, str)):
            for y in flatten(x):
                yield y
        else:
            yield x
```

Starting from Python 3.3, you can also write

```
def flatten(it):
    for x in it:
        if (isinstance(x, collections.Iterable) and
            not isinstance(x, str)):
            yield from flatten(x)
        else:
            yield x
```

Comment: Thank you very much! With my attempt I was very near to yours :-) Regards!

Comment: +1 - I keep forgetting about `yield from` and this was a nice reminder.

Comment: @JonClements: You "keep forgetting" features of a Python version wich hasn't even been released yet?  I'm surprised. :)

Comment: My crystal ball has recently been in full working order!? ;) [but on a serious note - I happen to follow PEPs]

Answer (score 0):

The non-recursive method is essentially an unrolling of the recursive method, using a stack:

```
def flatten(it):
    stack = []
    it = iter(it)
    while True:
        try:
            x = next(it)
        except StopIteration:
            if stack:
                it = stack.pop()
                continue
            else:
                return
        if isinstance(x, collections.Iterable) and not isinstance(x, str):
            stack.append(it)
            it = iter(x)
        else:
            yield x
```